# Future Callouts on Deletion of records

Tags: apex, callout, wsdl2apex

I am facing a very simple problem. I want to make a callout on the deletion of records, and push a bunch of to an external service. The problem is described below:

**Trigger Logic:**

```
Map <ID, Object__c> mapIdObj = new Map <ID, Object__c>();
if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isDelete){
   for(object__c obj : trigger.old){
      mapIdObj.put(obj.Id, obj); 
   }

   // Call the method to filter these records
   SampleApexClass.FilterRecords(mapIdObj, 'Delete');
}
```

**Apex Class Logic:**

```
   public static void FilterRecords(Map <ID, Object__c> mapIdObj, String Operation){ 
          // Filter the records
          Set <Id> setObjIds = new Set<Id>();
           for(Object__c obj : mapObj.keySet()){
                if(obj.abc__c = ''){
                    setObjIds.add(obj.Id);
                }
           }
        Async_CallOut(setObjIds);
   } 

  // CallOut
  @future(callout=true)
  public static void Async_CallOut(Set <Id> setObjIds){
      System.Debug(setObjIds);  // THIS PRINTS THE OBJECT IDS FINE**
      list <Object__c> listObj = [Select Name, Relationship__r.abc__c from Object__c where id in : setObjIds];
      System.Debug(listObj);  // THIS DOES NOT PRINT ANYTHING

      /***** PSEUDO CODE BELOW *****/

      // Make a callout using this list in another method

      // Fetch the response

      if(success)
        // UPDATE THE LIST OF OBJECT__C                <- THIS IS IMPORTANT

 }
```

The records are deleted before the callout is made. How can I make this work except for making this a synchronous callout? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Your record is already deleted when you call your future method, it's async. So you will never have access to it.

Comment: I know that. I am looking to workarounds apart from making a synchronous callout!

Comment: Instead of passing your list of id's to your future method, try to serialize a list of object with JSON.serialize and pass it to your future method. Then you deserialize it again.

Comment: Actually, you can't pass any list of objects in there! No data types containing references to classes or objects are allowed.

Comment: Your requirement is a bit bizarre. If you delete your record, why do you want to update it ?

Comment: Yes you can pass a list of object, that's why you serialize it. I put an example as an answer

Comment: The new code is over-complicated. There is no reason to pass a map and then extract only the keyset. Just send Trigger.oldMap.keyset().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create another object which will have the same fields as the record you're trying to delete.

In the before delete trigger I'd copy all fields across (dynamically) and create "a clone record" which will be marked with a checkbox "Send to external source".

Then either with a `@future` method or a batch I'd push those records marked as "Send to external source" and delete them once successfully sent out.

Comment: I am working on the same, just saw your answer now! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a custom object, then append "ALL ROWS" to your query and optionally use WHERE IsDeleted=true.

list  listObj = [Select Name from Object_*c where id in : setObjIds ALL ROWS];
OR
list  listObj = [Select Name from Object*_c where id in : setObjIds AND IsDeleted=true ALL ROWS];

That will give you what you want.
(ALL ROWS gives regular and deleted records. If you have a lot of records, specifying isDeleted=true AND using all rows will make your query a bit more selective, speeding execution.

Comment: That does not return anything for me. The query is not just simple, its a big relationship query so it does not return anything.

Comment: If you are querying parent records, then that will fail, as this record is in the process of being deleted and the relationship has already been severed. You will need to break the query into multiple parts, and will have to do a complex number of sets of Ids, which you can then use in a query. Plus, you must still use ALL ROWS.

Answer (score -1):

```
trigger MyObjectTrigger on TestApprovalProcess__c (before delete) {
    MyObjectHandler.Async_CallOut(JSON.serialize(Trigger.old));
}

public class MyObjectHandler
{
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void Async_CallOut(String myobjects){
        List<MyObject__c> records = ( List<MyObject__c>)JSON.deserialize(myobjects,List<MyObject__c>.class);
        records[0].ApprovalStatus__c = 'Async Deleted';
        System.debug('Deleted records'+records);
       // callout here
       if (success....)
       {   //not sure what you want to do here
           undelete records;
           update records;
       }
    }
}
```